# python - How to resolve "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (228, 1), indices imply (228, 7)"

Tags: python, pandas, foursquare, valueerror

I'm trying to finish off an assignment for a coursera course and am having a hard time getting an aspect of my code to work right.

I'm using the foursquare API to explore neighborhoods in portland and find which ones have bookstores (and similar venues) in them. I'm close to having it execute, but I keep flagging the above ValueError and don't know how to restructure my DF so that it has the correct shape.

Here is my code:

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, limit=500):

    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&query={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            CLIENT_ID, 
            CLIENT_SECRET, 
            VERSION,
            lat,
            lng,
            query, 
            radius, 
            LIMIT)

        try:
            results = requests.get(url, "none").json()['response']['groups'][0]['items']


            venues_list.extend([(
                name, 
                lat, 
                lng, 
                v['venue']['name'], 
                v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
                v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
                v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

        except KeyError:
            venues_list.extend([
                name,
                lat,
                lng]) 

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame(venues_list, columns = ['Neighborhood', 
                  'Neighborhood Latitude', 
                  'Neighborhood Longitude', 
                  'Venue', 
                  'Venue Latitude', 
                  'Venue Longitude', 
                  'Venue Category'])

    return(nearby_venues)

*** NEXT CELL***

PDX_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=PDX_NeighDF['Neighborhood'],
                             latitudes=PDX_NeighDF['Latitude'],
                             longitudes=PDX_NeighDF['Longitude']
                             )

PDX_venues.head()
```

I took the original function from a previous lab in the course so I know that it should work. The first cell actually executes fine, but the ValueError is being flagged in the next cell where I try to use the defined function. Which makes me think that the issue must be in the function itself. I had to make some modifications to it for my unique assignment, so that could be part of the problem. Here are the changes to the function I made outside of basic inputs:

1. Some neighborhoods in Portland don't have any venues that are returned in my API request and were flagging a 'KeyError" since they had no 'group' section in the returned json, so I had to add the "try / except" lines to except the neighborhoods that returned no venues. This worked fine when I first ran it and allowed the cell to execute. However going to use the function in the next cell then caused the "ValueError" to flag.
2. I attempted to fix the ValueError in the next cell by changing venues_list.append to .extend at the suggestion of another user in a stackoverflow post that was having a similar problem to mine. Didn't seem to help much as I still get the ValueError, but before it was flagged for having one element instead of 7 (same issue, different form).

Any help would be very appreciated, this has been a difficult project and I was able to get really far using my own resources, but this issue has completely stumped me. Thank you in advance!

Also, here is the full ValueError traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1677                 blocks = [
-> 1678                     make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
   1679                 ]

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype, fastpath)
   3283 
-> 3284     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   3285 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
   2791 
-> 2792         super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   2793 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    127                 "Wrong number of items passed {val}, placement implies "
--> 128                 "{mgr}".format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs))
    129             )

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 7

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-66be6cf8c7d3> in <module>
      1 PDX_venues = getNearbyVenues(names=PDX_NeighDF['Neighborhood'],
      2                              latitudes=PDX_NeighDF['Latitude'],
----> 3                              longitudes=PDX_NeighDF['Longitude']
      4                              )
      5 

<ipython-input-39-53e5a94bf83d> in getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, limit)
     39                   'Venue Latitude',
     40                   'Venue Longitude',
---> 41                   'Venue Category'])
     42 
     43     return(nearby_venues)

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    462                     mgr = arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    463                 else:
--> 464                     mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    465             else:
    466                 mgr = init_dict({}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    211         block_values = [values]
    212 
--> 213     return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
    214 
    215 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1686         blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]
   1687         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1688         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   1689 
   1690 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   1717         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
   1718     raise ValueError(
-> 1719         "Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed, implied)
   1720     )
   1721 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (228, 1), indices imply (228, 7)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Sure thing, I added it into my question above.

Comment: I think I have an idea. Inside the loop, try printing out *name*, *lat*, *lng* to see if a specific row in `PDX_NeighDF` is the issue. Next time it errs out, see these values in data frame. Is it first row? Anything special about them (i.e., NaNs)?

Answer (score 1):

Issue may come down to your `except` clause which is not wrapped in an embedded tuple like the `try` clause. As a result, `venues_list` extends each element of underlying collection. So instead of  `[(tuple of vals), tuple(val1, val2, val3), (tuple of vals)]` you pass `[(tuple of vals), val1, val2, val3, (tuple of vals)]` into `DataFrame` constructor.

```
except KeyError:
     venues_list.extend([(
           name,
           lat,
           lng)])
```

Consider also catching *any* exception which can be due to API request call and not just returned json. Also, include `numpy.nan` for missing columns (so `NaN` and not `None` results in data frame).

```
except Exception as e:
     print(e.message)

     venues_list.extend([(
           name,
           lat,
           lng,
           np.nan,
           np.nan,
           np.nan,
           np.nan)])
```